# Get all data from spreadsheet into html

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets

When I run this as a Google script (within code.gs) it works, however, when I take it to the index.html file I can't get the whole data from the spreadsheet.

sheets should be 3D, `sheets[0]` should show all the data in sheet 0 (rows x cols)
But instead in `data`, I get what it looks like a string (when I do `data[0]` it shows only the first character). Why?

Here is the code:

GAS

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate();
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
    .getContent();
}

function getSheetsData(){
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_key');         
  var sheets = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < ss.getSheets().length; ++i) {           
    sheets.push(ss.getSheets()[i].getDataRange().getDisplayValues());  
  }    
  return (sheets)
}
```

CLIENT SIDE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">    
    <?!= include('css'); ?>    

    <!-- the idea is to pull the data from the spreadsheet and build slides with the questions to show a Quiz of questions (not yet done)-->
    <script>
      var datas = null;
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result){ 
        datas = result;
        console.log(datas); //YES, datas has the data
      }).getSheetsData();
      console.log(datas);   //NO, datas is null
    </script>         
    </head>

  <body>    
  <h1>TESTS QUIZ [WEB APP]
    <br>
    <br>
      <!-- Build select options from spreadsheet sheets -->
      <?  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_key'); ?>
      <select class="classic" id="sheet" onchange="someFunctionWillGoHereToStartTheQuiz">
      <option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Choose Quiz</option>
      <? for (var i = 0; i < ss.getSheets().length; ++i) { ?>      
        <option value="<?=i?>"><?= ss.getSheets()[i].getSheetName() ?></option>   
      <? } ?>
      </select>  
      <br>
      <br>
  </h1>
  <!--some code will go here to show the questions in the page-->
```

Comment: Does your script have authorization with one of the two end-points mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app ? You need to be okay with either https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly or https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets Or more accurately, either of those two end-points need to be okay with you.

Comment: yes it does. I can see googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets under the project properties

Comment: You should build the html table from array using tags like `<tr></tr>`. You can't just put the array object in the html file and automatically expect it to show it all.

Comment: The problem is here: 

data = <?= sheets ?>;

I can only get passed on plain text, like a long string containing the text of all cells in the spreadsheet, but I can't get it formatted in the shape of an array, separating the elements

Comment: Ditch the whole use of snippets and build your page asynchronously. Use JSON format for sending lots of information (`JSON.stringify`, `JSON.parse`), especially if that information has a complex structure or banned types (like `Date`s). Review the [official best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion would be to use this method.

1. create a function server-side to get all datas
2. retrieve datas client -side using success handler and calling `google.script.run.myFunction()`

**GAS**

```
function getSheetsData(){
 ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id_key_spreadsheet');         
    var sheets = []; //except if you want to add more datas no need to declare a 3D array
    for (var i = 0; i < ss.getSheets().length; ++i) {
       // I'v corrected this part so you don't get any "out of bounds" errors
      sheets.push(ss.getSheets()[i].getDataRange().getDisplayValues());  
    }
  return (sheets)
}
```

**client side**

```
<script>
 var datas = null;
 google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(result)
   { 
     datas = result;
   }).getSheetsData();
</script>
```

now if you want to grab the first string consider using 2 times `[]` as so
 `datas[0][0]` as you are using  2D array. Your problem also might come from here.

**REFERENCES**

[google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into this. But I can't yet get the "datas", when I run console.log(datas) it says null. datas is only right when inside withSuccessHandler function().

By the way, there was one "h" missing.

Comment: @josemruiz Could you share with me your code. I'll make it work for sure. Best.Also this is perfectly normal you don't get data populated directly. As you run an asynchronous function so make a sleep function after callin `getSheetsData` and you'll see normally data is populated